# Android : Loading URL in webview from web display blank screen for first time

Tags: android, timer, webview

I am trying to load multiple URL in webview which automatically change after some time interval, everything is working fine except that when i run my application first time every time it show's blank screen for first 10 second (Which is basically time period which i have set) and then it load's first URL, i don't know why it is happening like this.

Below is my code

```
public class Gif_First extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;
CountDownTimer mTimer;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.animation);

    mTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        private String[] myArray = {
                "http://i.share.pho.to/efe195fd_o.gif",
                "http://i.share.pho.to/cf478918_o.gif",
                "http://i.share.pho.to/5ae5a0a9_o.gif",
                "http://i.share.pho.to/17d0c96f_o.gif",
                "http://i.share.pho.to/d2139e2d_o.gif" };
        int currentIndex = 0;

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            if (currentIndex < myArray.length) {
                mWebView.loadUrl(myArray[currentIndex]);
                currentIndex++;
            } else {
                currentIndex = 0;
                if (currentIndex < myArray.length)
                    mWebView.loadUrl(myArray[currentIndex]);
                currentIndex++;
                mTimer.start();
            }
            mTimer.start();
        }
    };

    mTimer.start();
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewActionView);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebSliderWebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(mWebView, url);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!",
                //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class WebSliderWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mTimer.cancel();
}
}
```

Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You have not set any url in outside your MuCountDown Class that's why you are getting error. It means you have to give

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

atleast one URL inside your Gif_First class.

Use below code,

```
mTimer.start();
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewActionView);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com");
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

syntax " `CountDownTimer(start time, intervel time)` " .. replace the code `mTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000)` instead of `mTimer = new CountDownTimer(0, 1000)` hope it will work. happy coding...

Comment: No, It is giving NullPointerException at      mWebView.loadUrl(myArray[currentIndex]); on onFinish() method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this custom :

```
private class MyCountDown extends CountDownTimer
 {
long duration, interval;
public MyCountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    duration = millisInFuture;
    interval = countDownInterval;
    start();
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {

}

@Override
public void onTick(long duration) {

}   
}
```

Comment: how to use this class, because i have implemented this in my code but no changes, same thing is happening, can you just give example how to use this in my class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Gif_First extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;
CountDownTimer mTimer;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.animation);

mTimer = new MyCountDown(10000, 1000);
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewActionView);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebSliderWebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(mWebView, url);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done!",
            //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
            String description, String failingUrl) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
    mWebView.goBack();
    return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

private class WebSliderWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
}

public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
mTimer.cancel();
}

class MyCountDown extends CountDownTimer
{
 long duration, interval;
 private String[] myArray = {
            "http://i.share.pho.to/efe195fd_o.gif",
            "http://i.share.pho.to/cf478918_o.gif",
            "http://i.share.pho.to/5ae5a0a9_o.gif",
            "http://i.share.pho.to/17d0c96f_o.gif",
            "http://i.share.pho.to/d2139e2d_o.gif" };
 int currentIndex = 0;
 public MyCountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
  super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  duration = millisInFuture;
  interval = countDownInterval;
  start();
 }

 @Override
 public void onFinish() {
  if (currentIndex < myArray.length) {
            mWebView.loadUrl(myArray[currentIndex]);
            currentIndex++;
        } else {
            currentIndex = 0;
            if (currentIndex < myArray.length)
                mWebView.loadUrl(myArray[currentIndex]);
            currentIndex++; 
        }
 }

 @Override
 public void onTick(long duration) {

 }   
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, I did the same thing but still it is holding for 10 seconds.

Comment: chane first parameter to 0

Comment: If i do like this, mTimer = new CountDownTimer(0, 10000) it is showing error NullPointerException at mWebView.loadUrl(myArray[currentIndex]); on onFinish() method.

Comment: put check on that line: if (mArray[currentIndex]!=null)

Comment: Nope, still not getting done, giving same error on same method.

Comment: Show me your check and line

Comment: public void onFinish() {
    if (currentIndex < myArray.length) {
     if (myArray[currentIndex] != null) {
      mWebView.loadUrl(myArray[currentIndex]);
      currentIndex++;
     }
    } else {
     currentIndex = 0;
     if (currentIndex < myArray.length)
      mWebView.loadUrl(myArray[currentIndex]);
     currentIndex++;
     mTimer.start();
    }
    mTimer.start();
   }
  };

Comment: remove mTimer.start() from method. And also show me the line when exception come.

Comment: I have removed mTimer.start but still getting an error, you can see my  logcat http://i.share.pho.to/750b0cfb_o.png

Comment: show the error line in java class... And one more thing be sure that may be your webview which you are using is null.

Comment: it is on line 45, for more reference use this link http://i.share.pho.to/213fa985_o.png

Comment: so the line 45 is       mWebView.loadUrl(myArray[currentIndex]);

Comment: It may be that webview that u are using is null. again verify that. put debugger breakpoint there and check webview here is null or not.

Comment: but the problem what i am facing is just first time only, after that it is loading all the images one after one, so the problem is not in webview, because when i am loading this image one by one in separate activity then it is working fine.

Comment: initiliaze this array in constructor before start()  method call.
myArray = {
            "http://i.share.pho.to/efe195fd_o.gif",
            "http://i.share.pho.to/cf478918_o.gif",
            "http://i.share.pho.to/5ae5a0a9_o.gif",
            "http://i.share.pho.to/17d0c96f_o.gif",
            "http://i.share.pho.to/d2139e2d_o.gif" };
And upvote this answer if helpful

Answer (score 0):

There are possible reasons causing "WebView goes blank after finish loading page":

1. If your WebView part defined in the layout xml file has dimensions like

   ```
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   ```

   or

   ```
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   ```

   Then after the page is loaded, the content is defined and WebView tries to "wrap" it, thus in some cases reduces the view's dimensions into 0dp and make your WebView invisible.
   Solution: change all those into fill_parent

   ```
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   ```
2. This may be caused by an SSL certification error. Try this:

   ```
   public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
       handler.proceed();
   }
   ```